# Волшебный запрос который роняет Apache

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, idiorm

Работаю локально(OpenServer) через Idiorm, и вот такой запрос роняет Apache

```js
select cards.uid, cards.balance, cards.expires_at, profiles.name, profiles.gender, profiles.phone, profiles.email, profiles.send_sms, profiles.send_email, profiles.birthday, cards.is_activated as act, cards.is_blocked as block
from cards left join profiles on profiles.id = cards.profile_id
where cards.client_id = 4
```

Месяца полтора назад, тоже такая ситуевина была-запрос ложил на лопатки Apache,чуть поизвращавшись сделал другой запрос который работал нормально.

Логи апача пусты-молча в даун уходит.

Может кто объяснить в чем прикол? Я просто не понимаю в чем дело

Comment: Имена таблиц и полей в апострофы не пробовали взять?

Comment: @Visman,попробуем

Comment: @Visman,н-и-ф-и-г-а. Один черт роняет. Пофиг даже что запрос этот не работает, другой сформировать можно-просто нужно знать какого черта он роняет апач,чтобы в будущем подобного избежать-самый то прикол что в phpMyAdmine и HeidiSQL(идет в пакете OpenServer'а) все прекрасно исполняется....

Comment: без `LEFT JOIN` тоже падает? Переставить местами поля в выдаче? Убрать поля по одному из выдачи?

Comment: Скорее всего банальная ошибка в ПО на конкретном железе. Можно попробовать сменить версию модуля PHP или версию Apache через настройки OpenServer.

Comment: @AlexKrass,все постоянно обновляется-так что по идее такого не должно быть.Если еще подобное случиться-придется копать в чем трабла,ибо не кошерно держать в выборке более 20 полей когда нужны только 12)

Comment: а если алиасы с полей убрать?

Comment: Может какие-то алиасы не нравятся, т.е. совпадают с командами, например, block.

Comment: Norritt, msi. Как по мне, в таком случае он должен выдать ошибку, а не наглухо упасть. Мне кажется, что дело где-то глубже во внутреннем взаимодействии, чем в просто запросе.

Comment: @msi,как я уже писал не в пыхе нормально все-было бы в словах-командах там бы тоже падало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

причины падения могут быть разные, по моему мнению наиболее вероятна просадка по памяти апача или мускуля, для того что бы понять советую использывать функцию для анализа плана (explain), и еще поглядеть надо в логи апача, что ему конкретно не нравится и там уже копать подробнее.

Answer (score -1):

Слово block зарезервировано, используйте тильды или поменяйся алиас
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html